# image quantization

Tags: lookup-tables, quantization

In Efford's cd there is a code for grayscale image quantization:

```
int n = 8 - numBits;//numBits will be taken as input
float scale = 255.0f / (255 >> n);
byte[] tableData = new byte[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
  tableData[i] = (byte) Math.round(scale*(i >> n));
LookupOp lookup =
 new LookupOp(new ByteLookupTable(0, tableData), null);
BufferedImage result = lookup.filter(getSourceImage(), null);
return result;
```

I am trying to convert this code for 24 bit color image.
But dont know if I am correct?

my try:
              int n = 24 - numBits;

```
    float scale = 16777216.0f / (16777216 >> n);
    byte[] tableData = new byte[16777216];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16777216; ++i)
      tableData[i] = (byte) Math.round(scale*(i >> n));
    LookupOp lookup =
     new LookupOp(new ByteLookupTable(0, tableData), null);
    result = lookup.filter(img2, null);
    //return result;
```

and this gives result inmage till numBits>=17, if numBits<17 then i get complete black image.
Am I doing it correctlly?

please help.
Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

That code quantizes only grayscale images, not color images. This means that it handles only one color channel at a time.

Besides, if you are doing 24bit -> 8bit, you probably want to construct a **palette** instead of simple quantization.

Comment: thanks jpa
but then i read lookup.filter takes care of color image model
i just want to quantize color image using similar logic

Comment: public final BufferedImage filter(BufferedImage src,
                                  BufferedImage dst)
Performs a lookup operation on a BufferedImage. If the color model in the source image is not the same as that in the destination image, the pixels will be converted in the destination. If the destination image is null, a BufferedImage will be created with an appropriate ColorModel. An IllegalArgumentException might be thrown if the number of arrays in the LookupTable does not meet the restrictions stated in the class comment above, or if the source image has an IndexColorModel.